# Cannot implicitly convert type 'ulong' to 'bool'

Tags: c#, primes

I get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'ulong' to 'bool'

in here (u*u) `for (ulong u = 2; u * u; u++)`

chunk of code below.

```
static bool IsPrime(ulong Num)
{
     if (Num < 2) return false;
     else if (Num < 4) return true;
     else if (Num % 2 == 0) return false;
     for (ulong u = 2; u * u; u++)
         if (Num % u == 0) return false;
     return true;
}
```

Comment: What about the error don't you understand?  You have `u*u` where a boolean is expected, and that's not a boolean.  If you asked me if I understood your question and I responded with `42` what would you think?

Comment: The second component of the `for` syntax determines the stop condition of the loop. It has to be a boolean. You're probably looking for `u < (u*u);`?

Comment: @NateBarbettini The condition you mentioned would only be true if `u` was `0`, or if the multiplication overflowed.

Comment: @Servy Ugh, you're right. Read it too fast and didn't think. I think Mehrzad Chehraz has it right.

Comment: Thanks for all the input guys, youre very fast :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) about for keyword :

> Every for statement defines initializer, **condition**, and iterator
>   sections. These sections usually determine how many times the loop
>   iterates.

So the second part is a condition and must be implicitly converted to bool. Since long type cannot be converted implicitly, u get a compile time error.
I guess it was what you where trying to do:

```
static bool IsPrime(ulong Num)
{
   if (Num < 2)
        return false;
   else if (Num < 4)
        return true;
   else if (Num % 2 == 0)
        return false;
   for (ulong u = 2; u * u < Num; u++)
       if (Num % u == 0)
          return false;
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Yep, that was exactly the thing I was missing. Something rang a bell about a condition, but I just couldn't figure out where. Thank You very much for solving the problem!